# 24H Dateformat Not working

Tags: fullcalendar, mendix

I got something that is completely doing my head in. In the fullcalendar (mendix) widget I'm trying to show a 24H format. Whatever I try... It's just not working. I've filled in the custom date format, H:(mm) but it just doesn't work!

What I'm seeing right now is this:

[image: http://puu.sh/b3ilY/0e7661cc0c.png]

I want to see the 24H timeformat in H:mm, so 14:00 - 15:00 - 16:00 etc!

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried changing the time format into HH:mm? Though I don't think it should matter.
Without code snippets or knowing anything about this code/widget I don't think many people will be able to answer this here.

Comment: Any solution for your problem ! same issue for me